# Editar arquivos em um servidor na rede local, é possível?

Tags: wamp

Criei um servidor no **computador "A**" (usando WAMP Server) e fiz configurações para que ele permita o acesso do **computador "B"**, via rede local.

Nesse sentido, o computador "B" consegue ler os diretórios, acessar o phpMyAdmin e todo o resto.

No entanto, não sei se é possível e como fazer para que o computador "B" possa editar ou criar arquivos no diretório www do servidor instalado no computador "A".

Comment: @dvd Penso de tal forma, mas não sei como é o procedimento para acessar o www e editar os arquivos presentes no servidor, usando o computador "B". Teria como me ensinar a fazer isso e ativar compartilhamento para além de só leitura?

Comment: Para acessar o servidor utilizo o IP local do computador "A", na barra de endereços do chrome. No entanto, com isso só consigo visualizar os projetos. Por isso, quero saber como modificá-los ou adicionar outros, remotamente.

Comment: Talvez ajude a entenderem melhor, se eu esclarecer que meu objetivo é criar uma espécie de LivePreview entre dois notebooks.

Comment: Ambos usam Windows 7 64 bits. Já o servidor está usando Apache 2.4.27, PHP 5.6.31 e MySQL 5.7.19.

Comment: Talvez criando um grupo na rede doméstica e compartilhando a pasta na rede o outro computador possa acessar a pasta.

Comment: Se tiveres alguma solução alternativa para LivePreview com dois notebooks, também servirá.

Comment: @dvd E para rodar o PHP, futuramente. Usando um grupo funcionaria?

Comment: Não sei dizer. Não mexo muito com isso, só testando mesmo pra saber. A única coisa que me vem à mente é compartilhamento de pastas e arquivos na rede Windows. Quando um PC ingressa na rede, ele terá acessos aos arquivos das pastas compartilhadas.

Comment: Deu certo, cara. Vlw! @dvd

Comment: Estou compartilhando o diretório www do PC que tem o WampServer. Dessa forma, acredito que posso desenvolver em um notebook e visualizar em outro, tornando o processo mais cômodo.

Comment: Exatamente. Se quiser postar uma resposta seria bom pra referência futura. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Meu objetivo era fazer uma espécie de LivePreview com dois notebooks, já que não tenho dois monitores para compartilhar tela com HDMI.

Dessa maneira, com ajuda do @dvd, apesar de a solução não usar somente o WampServer, obtive êxito.

Assim, tudo o que fiz foi criar um grupo doméstico, no Windows 7. Portanto, pude compartilhar o diretório www no grupo e ganhei direito de visualizá-lo/editá-lo.